# PhoneGap apk not executing POST action

Tags: android, cordova

In my PhoneGap app, I have this code in order to test AJAX REST communication:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#test").click(function() {
        alert("OK");
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        data: {},
        url: "http://localhost:8080/test-notifier-web/RegisterServlet",
        });
    });
});
<div class="row col-centered">
    <button type="submit" id="test">Submit</button>                 
</div>
```

Executing this code in Chrome is ok, i get logging on my console and everything works fine. When I build apk with `cordova build android` and test it on my Genymotion device I get no response from server. At the some time, using Genymotion browser to test it via web is ok.

I created a new blank app with this code and it's working good with apk. Anyone could help me?

This is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="it.paytas.mobile" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Paytas Mobile</name>
    <description>
        A blank PhoneGap app.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Paste your config.xml and Content-Security-Policy

Comment: @Eric posted config.xml, where can i find Content-Security-Policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the "allow-intent" metas to your config.xml

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

You need to add the Content-Security-Policy meta to your index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' gap://ready file://* 'unsafe-inline' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; img-src *">
```

Also be sure you have the [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) plugin installed.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Fixed this way, thank you